# Spark DataFrame GroupBy collect_list and fill missing valeus with 0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe of this kind

```
+------+--------+--------+
|    id|category|quantity|
+------+--------+--------+
|merch1|   fruit|    20.0|
|merch1| veggies|   300.0|
|merch1|   diary|    10.0|
|merch1|organics|    12.0|
|merch1|  frozen|    11.0|
|merch2|   fruit|     6.0|
|merch2|   diary|     6.0|
|merch2|  frozen|     8.0|
|merch3| veggies|    13.0|
|merch3|organics|     4.0|
|merch3|  frozen|    10.0|
|merch4|   fruit|    28.0|
|merch4|organics|    11.0|
+------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to groupBy id and generate a vector on quantity as an ordered collect_list, such that if the category is absent it fills with 0.0. The distinct categories are

```
+--------+                                                                      
|category|
+--------+
|  frozen|
|   diary|
| veggies|
|organics|
|   fruit|
+--------+
```

For example for merch1 since everything is present the vector
for merch1 it is  `[11.0, 10.0, 300.0, 12.0, 20.0]`
for merch2 it is `[8.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0]`
for merch3 it is `[10.0, 0.0, 13.0, 4.0, 0.0]`
for merch4 it is `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 11.0]`

Hence the final dataframe I am looking for is

```
+------+--------+----------------------+
|    id| vector                        |
+------+--------+----------------------+
|merch1|[11.0, 10.0, 300.0, 12.0, 20.0]|
|merch2|[8.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0]      |
|merch3|[10.0, 0.0, 13.0, 4.0, 0.0]    |
|merch4|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 11.0]    |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this in two steps, convert rows to columns at group level(here `id`) using `pivot` and use `array` SQL function to create the list as expected.

```
from pyspark.sql import function as f
df.show()
+------+--------+--------+
|    id|category|quantity|
+------+--------+--------+
|merch1|   fruit|    20.0|
|merch1| veggies|   300.0|
|merch1|   diary|    10.0|
|merch1|organics|    12.0|
|merch1|  frozen|    11.0|
|merch2|   fruit|     6.0|
|merch2|   diary|     6.0|
|merch2|  frozen|     8.0|
|merch3| veggies|    13.0|
|merch3|organics|     4.0|
|merch3|  frozen|    10.0|
|merch4|   fruit|    28.0|
|merch4|organics|    11.0|
+------+--------+--------+  
    
df1 = df.groupby('id').pivot('category').agg(f.first('quantity')).fillna(0)
df1.show()
+------+-----+------+-----+--------+-------+
|    id|diary|frozen|fruit|organics|veggies|
+------+-----+------+-----+--------+-------+
|merch2|  6.0|   8.0|  6.0|     0.0|    0.0|
|merch4|  0.0|   0.0| 28.0|    11.0|    0.0|
|merch1| 10.0|  11.0| 20.0|    12.0|  300.0|
|merch3|  0.0|  10.0|  0.0|     4.0|   13.0|
+------+-----+------+-----+--------+-------+
    
df1.select('id',f.array(df1.columns[1:]).name('vector')).show(truncate=False)
+------+-------------------------------+
|id    |vector                         |
+------+-------------------------------+
|merch2|[6.0, 8.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0]      |
|merch4|[0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 11.0, 0.0]    |
|merch1|[10.0, 11.0, 20.0, 12.0, 300.0]|
|merch3|[0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 4.0, 13.0]    |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: I had to make changes to make it adaptable to spark dataframe.